# How to apply ng-if with filter for filtering records and present two different views in the same page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am pretty new to AngularJS and is learning that from [here](http://tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/), but am stuck with the below experiment of mine.

I have the below data:

```
var people = ([
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Peter",
    age: 21},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "David",
    age: 10},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Anil",
    age: 22}
    ]);
```

What I want to do is that, **if the age is greater than 20**, then I have to display all the three fields (i.e. id, name, age)

```
ID    Name  Age
1     Peter  21
3     Anil   22
```

If the **age is less than 20,**, then only 2 fields will appear (e.g. id, name)

```
ID    Name  
2     David
```

**What I have tried so far?**

**app.js**

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope,$window) {

    $scope.people = ([
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Peter",
    age: 21},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "David",
    age: 20},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Anil",
    age: 22}
    ])  
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>   
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">

                <table  border="1" >
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>        
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="person in people" >
                        <td><span>{{person.id}}</span></td>
                        <td><span>{{person.name}}</span></td>
                        <td><span>{{person.age}}</span></td>       
                    </tr>
                </table>

        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was going through some tutorials in the net and came upon the concept of **ng-if** that will help to do this along with **filter**. (I think so.. correct me if I am in the wrong direction)

But I cannot just fit this into the application.

Also, I want to show the records in the same page(i.e. index.html)

Seeking help for that.

**Plunker:**  http://plnkr.co/edit/hLaw38fCMaclrHiaCH3X?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will look like below.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter: search">
    <td><span>{{person.id}}</span></td>
    <td><span>{{person.name}}</span></td>
    <td ng-if="person.age<20"><span>{{person.age}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bPOFLAHm3S6GstVL3bq?p=preview)

**Edit 1**

You will need to create extra filter which will give you the filter content has under 20 person or not.

**Markup**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th ng-if="(people| filter: search| filter: underTwenty: 20).length > 1">Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter: search">
        <td><span>{{person.id}}</span></td>
        <td><span>{{person.name}}</span></td>
        <td ng-if="person.age<20"><span>{{person.age}}</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Filter**

```
myApp.filter('underTwenty', function() {
    return function(values, limit) {
        var returnValue = [];
        angular.forEach(values, function(val, ind) {
            if (val.age < limit) returnValue.push(val);
        });
        return returnValue
    }
});
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uZXHaxB3tfKr2ZS35mAH?p=preview)

**Edit 2**

As per requested changes by OP

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" ng-init="ageToShow=(people| underTwenty: 20).length >= 1">
  <tr>{{ageToShow}}
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th ng-if="!ageToShow">Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter: search">
    <td><span>{{person.id}}</span>
    </td>
    <td><span>{{person.name}}</span>
    </td>
    <td ng-if="!ageToShow"><span>{{person.age}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/laRsPD6WQz2aSh8kL2gC?p=preview)

Comment: When the age is less than 20 it should display only 2 fields tat is ID and Name but the age should not display ....

Comment: you mean to say column should be hidden?

Comment: @anilchean take a look at my plunkr

Comment: but what i am asking is if any 1 persons age is less than 20 than the entire age column should not appear....plz help me wit this

Comment: Awesome answer (filter: search) Love it!!